# SQL Server: Ordering by date in the future when year is not known

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this information from a Table: The due date day and month (eg. 16/11 for 16th November) of events that repeat every year.

I need to create a View, sorted by how far it is in the future.

(eg. If it is currently 16 Nov 2010, then 31/12 means 31 Dec 2010 and it comes before 1/1 which means 1 Jan 2011)

Let's assume the Event table has these 3 columns

```
|------------------------|
|         Event          |
|------------------------|
| ID | DueDay | DueMonth |
|------------------------|
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you only planning on holding a maximum of a years worth of data?

Comment: yeah, the table could be wrong. Thank you everyone for all the excellent answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any event in the table with a dues day/month ahead of current day/month will occur *this*year. Any event with a due day/month behind current day/month will occur *next* year. Any event due next year is further than any event due this year.

Now that being said, what you ask for is not possible because you ask for `...a View, sorted by...` which is a concept that does not exists. **Views are not sorted**. Only **queries** are sorted. So you can create a view that projects the proper event date and then the **query from the view must use ORDER BY** to get the events sorted by event date:

```
create table Events (
 id int identity(1,1) not null, 
 DueDay int not null, 
 DueMonth int not null);
go

insert into Events (DueDay, DueMonth) 
values  (1,1), (15,11), (31,12);
go

create view eventsDate as
select id, dateadd(day, DueDay-1,
  dateadd (month, DueMonth-1,
     dateadd(year, 
         case when DueMonth < month(getdate()) or
            (DueMonth = month(getdate()) and 
             DueDay < day(getdate()))
         then year(getdate())-1899
         else year(getdate())-1900 end, 
         '19000101'))) as DueDate
    from Events;
```

To get the events by order, the query must include an order by:

```
select * from eventsDate order by DueDate desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, DueDay, DueMonth
FROM Event
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN DueMonth > DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
              OR (
                     DueMonth = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
                     AND DueDay >= DATEPART(day, GETDATE())
                 )
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    DueMonth,
    DueDay
```

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the Day and Month compared to the current date - if it is greater than the current date (excluding the year) set it to current year, otherwise set it to current year +1.

```
Select id, dueday, duemonth, 
    CASE WHEN duedate||duemonth||datepart(yy, getdate()) > getdate() 
        then duedate||duemonth||datepart(yy, getdate()) 
        else duedate||duemonth||dateadd(yy, 1, datepart(yy, getdate())) as fullDate
from event
order by fullDate
```

Sorry about the syntax - nothing to test it on :( , you should get the idea though.

Ideally, you want to be storing a timestamp column or have an extra part for the year though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is if you always assume that the dates are in the current year if the due date / due month is after the current date and in the next year if the due date / due month is before the current date.